# php code for creating .pdf file is not working on server

Tags: php, javascript, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am using PHP code for creating .pdf file and I am filing forms values in that .pdf file.

On localhost the code is working fine it creates .pdf ,edit .pdf file ....
But when i am putting same code on another server it's not creating .pdf and edit to......

the code is-

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF_result extends FPDF {
    function __construct ($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'pt', $format = 'Letter', $margin = 5 ) {
        $this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $format);
        $this->SetTopMargin($margin);
        $this->SetLeftMargin($margin);
        $this->SetRightMargin($margin);
        //$this->SetRightMargin1($margin1);
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);
    }

    function Header () {
        //$this->SetLeftMargin(85);
        $this->SetLeftMargin(5);
         $this->Image('header3.jpg',25,15,560);
         $this->SetLeftMargin(25);
    //  $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
    //  $this->SetFillColor(36, 96, 84);
    //  $this->SetTextColor(225);
    //  $this->Cell(0, 30, "YouHack MCQ Results", 0, 1, 'C', true);
    }

 function Footer()
{
    //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    //Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    //Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'ifs , india',0,0,'C');
}


function Generate_Table($subjects, $marks) {
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
//  $this->SetFillColor(94, 188, z);
$this->SetFillColor(94, 188, 225);
    $this->SetLineWidth(1);
    $this->Cell(427, 25, "Subjects", 'LTR', 0, 'C', true);
    $this->Cell(100, 25, "Marks", 'LTR', 1, 'C', true);

    $this->SetFont('Arial', '');
    $this->SetFillColor(238);
    $this->SetLineWidth(0.2);
    $fill = false;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subjects); $i++) {
        $this->Cell(427, 20, $subjects[$i], 1, 0, 'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell(100, 20,  $marks[$i], 1, 1, 'R', $fill);
        $fill = !$fill;
    }
    $this->SetX(367);
    //$this->Cell(100, 20, "Total", 1);
//  $this->Cell(100, 20,  array_sum($marks), 1, 1, 'R');
}

}
```

(its not complete code)

What is the exact problem?

Comment: what is the exact error / output / warning / message you are getting ?

Comment: ftp is not a server, its a protocol for transferring files

Comment: Take care you have error logging and reporting enabled on your server (check your php.ini configuration) and then look into the error log. It should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @Arfeen : i am not getting any error or warning, just browser replies file not found, that means .pdf file.

Comment: @Dagon whatever its protocol or server, point is what is the soluction? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is working on localhost, maybe it's a permission problem on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error log. It's usually located in `/var/log/apache/error.log`

if you're logged into your server, type

```
tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log
```

and reload the page -- any errors will show here. Paste them here if you need help diagnosing them

Answer (score 0):

Seems like permission issue. set permission on the directory where the pdf file is expected to create.